# How can I delay the speed of hover purely via CSS3 for a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

Please review the JSFiddle I am using: http://jsfiddle.net/txdwg/2/

HTML:

```
<a href="#">Hover here</a>
<div>Show me now!</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  display:none; 
  width:100px; 
  height:100px; 
  background:red; 
  margin:20px;
  }
a {
  font-size:16px; 
  font-weight:bold;
  }
```

JS:

```
(function($){
$.fn.hoverDelay = function(over, out, ms){
    var delay, ms, that;
    ms = ms || 500;
    that = this;

    that.bind('mouseenter.hoverDelay', function(e){
        delay = setTimeout(function(){
            over.call(that, e);
        }, ms);
    }).bind('mouseleave.hoverDelay', function(e){
        clearTimeout(delay);
        out.call(that, e);
    });
};

})(jQuery);

$(function(){
$('a').hoverDelay(function(){
    $('div').fadeIn(300);        
}, function(){
    $('div').fadeOut(300);    
}, 300);

});
```

But instead of JS I want to do this via CSS3.  How can I still use the hover pseudo selector and have a similar animation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/bvgVK/2/

```
div {
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; 
    background: red; 
    margin: 20px;
    -webkit-opacity: 0;
    -moz-opacity: 0;
    -ms-opacity: 0;
    -o-opacity: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms;
    -moz-transition: opacity 300ms;
    -ms-transition: opacity 300ms;
    -o-transition: opacity 300ms;
    transition: opacity 300ms;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 300ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 300ms;
    -ms-transition-delay: 300ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 300ms;
    transition-delay: 300ms;
}

a {
    font-size: 16px; 
    font-weight: bold;
}

a:hover + div {
    -webkit-opacity: 1;
    -moz-opacity: 1;
    -ms-opacity: 1;
    -o-opacity: 1;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Is something like that with all the vendor prefixes, but as uross suggested, go to that page or use http://cssprefixer.appspot.com/ or something else, but animations without js or flash or something else in MSIE < 10, hummm... dunno.

Comment: Be careful for different browsers support, you can read more about it here: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transitions/

Comment: Or you can use http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/, http://compass-style.org/ ... but I wanted to keep it simple since is CSS3 after all.

Comment: Thanks coma but this doesn't work on Safari and IE.  I'll see the link you posted as well.

Comment: Ok, you asked for something without js, only css3, let me use the vendor prefixes then.